# How to rearrange data in r

Tags: r, r-table

I am not able to rearrange my data in R. I am using following code.

```
data_1=read.table(file="filename.csv",sep=",")
```

I am getting...

```
               Month     Open      High      Low        Close
April-2015     27954.86  29094.61  26897.54  27011.31    NA
May-2015       27204.63  28071.16  26423.99  27828.44    NA
June-2015      27770.79  27968.75  26307.07  27780.83    NA
July-2015      27823.65  28578.33  27416.39  28114.56    NA
```

But I want it as...

```
Month          Open      High      Low       Close
April-2015     27954.86  29094.61  26897.54  27011.31
May-2015       27204.63  28071.16  26423.99  27828.44
June-2015      27770.79  27968.75  26307.07  27780.83
July-2015      27823.65  28578.33  27416.39  28114.56
```

Can someone help me please.

Thank you so much.

Comment: perhaps `row.names = NULL` ?

Comment: Please check your input csv file if there is a comma before first column name "Month"

Comment: Show us the first five lines of the file

Comment: Thank you so much guys for your help I got the answer... In my file there was comma added at last line that's why i was getting that as answer... now its working its fine....

Answer (score 0):

```
# My input file abcde.csv looks like below:

,One,Two,Three
a,b,c
c,b,d
a,b,c

# What happend when you read the above file
data <- read.csv("abcde.csv",sep=",",header=TRUE)
data
  X One Two Three
1 a  b   c   NA
2 c  b   d   NA
3 a  b   c   NA
```

Remove the `comma` in the first line in your input file before column name `Month`, save it and then again read it in the same way. This time it would work.

```
# If you also do not want to display row names given by R, you can print like this
print (data, row.names=FALSE)
  One Two Three
  a    b   c   
  c    b   d   
  a    b   c
```

Hope this sample helps.